# pg_dump issue while dumping single schema

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

pg_dump does refuse to dump a given schema in my DB.

```
pg_dump -d <dbname> -s -n dm_geo -f <filename>
```

### Result

```
-- 
-- PostgreSQL database dump 
--

-- Dumped from database version 9.5.4
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 9.5.4

SET statement_timeout = 0; 
...
SET row_security =off;

--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

Comment: Under which user do you run `pg_dump`? Does it has (PostgreSQL) access to the schema you are trying to dump?

Comment: check system and database logs for unusual occurrences that could have terminated the dump early.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your command is wrong, Follow the below command to dump dm_geo schema.

### To dump without data

```
pg_dump dbname -s -n dm_geo -f backup.sql
```

## To dump schema and data

```
pg_dump dbname -n dm_geo -f backup.sql
```

Comment: sorry, due to "tags" seems my command got incorrect in the post. I did run exactly as you do indicate  but got incomplete results

Comment: I have edited your question, please take a review, So someone can able to  identify the exact problem.

Comment: This dump command will work actually, I verified. Kindly share if you got any info message while taking the dump.