# pg_dump does not return schema for repmgr objects

Tags: postgresql-10, pg-dump, repmgr

While trying to browse `repmgr.monitoring_history`, I noticed it has many tens of millions of records. Wanting to get a peak at the indexes that (may or may not) already exist on the table, I try a quickie [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/app-pgdump.html)...

```sh
# pg_dump -U postgres -d repmgr --table=repmgr.monitoring_history --schema-only
```

...which frustratingly returns only the boilerplate header/footer info...

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 10.8
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 10.8

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

...well darnit! Did I typo something?

```sh
# pg_dump -U postgres -d repmgr --table=foo.bar --schema-only
pg_dump: no matching tables were found
```

...no... I *am* connected to the host I thought I was, right?...

```sh
# psql -U postgres -d repmgr -c 'select count(*) from repmgr.monitoring_history;'
  count   
----------
 43597932
(1 row)
```

... so what gives? Why can't I dump the schema definition for this table?

---

<sup>Possibly also worth noting that **pg_dump -s -d repmgr** returns only the **CREATE EXTENSION...** & **CREATE SCHEMA...** commands and none of the tables. The behaviour is consistent across a few different repmgr installations. Perhaps I'm having the same issue as [this guy](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194098/)?</sup>

<sup>Also *also* worth noting that attempting to dump data *only* also comes up blank. And that I've tried **sudo -u postgres pg_dump...** as well. Dumping another database on the same cluster works just fine returning data & schema as expected.</sup>

Comment: Did you try `--table=monitoring_history`?

Answer (score 2):

> *Beginning with repmgr [5.2](https://repmgr.org/docs/current/release-5.2.0.html), the metadata tables associated with the repmgr extension (repmgr.nodes, repmgr.events and repmgr.monitoring_history) have been marked as dumpable.*

This answer found in [FAQ: How can I exclude repmgr metadata from pg_dump output?](https://repmgr.org/docs/current/faq-repmgr.html#FAQ-REPMGR-EXCLUDE-METADATA-FROM-DUMP:%7E:text=Beginning%20with%20repmgr%205.2,have%20been%20marked%20as%20dumpable)