# Dump pglogical Config to files

Tags: postgresql, pg-logical

We use the tool etckeeper to keep track of the configuration of servers.

I would like to dump the configuration of pglogical to files for this purpose.

I tried this:

```
db@host:~$ pg_dump -t 'pglogical.replication_set'
```

But the output looks empty:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 11.5
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 11.5

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

How can I dump the configuration of pglogical?

Use Case:

- dump it hourly and store it in git to see what was changed.
- compare two hosts to see if the configuration is equal.

Answer (score 1):

The table belongs to the extension `pglogical`, so `pg_dump` doesn't dump it.

Objects that belong to an extension don't get included in the dump, they are subsumed in the `CREATE EXTENSION` command from a database dump, because that object will be created by the `CREATE EXTENSION` command. If the object itself got dumped too, restoring the dump would cause an error, because the object already exists after `CREATE EXTENSION`.

You could use `psql` and do something like

```
\copy (SELECT * FROM pglogical.replication_set ORDER BY ...) TO 'some.file' (FORMAT 'csv')
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Now the next question is here. What do these tables and columns of pglogical mean? I asked here for docs: https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pglogical/issues/221

Comment: You asked at the right place.

Comment: "_Objects that belong to an extension don't get included in the dump_", if you'd care to elaborate on that a bit more, [I was having a similar issue a while back](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/240199/68127).

Comment: I tried to spell it out - I guess I am too familiar with this stuff, so i assume that it is obvious.